# Restricting an image size

Tags: css

Take a look at this - http://thegalaxyseries.com/amazon. The images of flags in the footer render properly when I view this on a PC. However, they enlarge and appear grainy on a phone. Here is a CSS I'm using.

```css
#footer {
  display: block;
  max-width: 32px !important;
  max-height: 32px !importent;
    image: url(http://static1.squarespace.com/static/5653b243e4b00b10015d2a20/t/565f318be4b02e4017e3bd55/1449079179674/flag-icon-us.gif);
}
```

what am i missing?

Comment: `image: url`? Is that even valid? Where's your HTML?

Comment: no it's not a valid css..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check it out:
http://jsfiddle.net/u7ft319o/2/

html:

```
<div id="footer">
  <img  class ="footer-image" src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/5653b243e4b00b10015d2a20/t/565f318be4b02e4017e3bd55/1449079179674/flag-icon-us.gif"/>
</div>
```

css:

```
#footer {
  display: block;
  max-width: 32px !important;
  max-height: 32px !importent;
}

.footer-image{
  max-width: 32px !important;
  max-height: 32px !importent;
}
```